# Equivariant $K$-homology with $G$-compact support

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $G$ be a discrete countable group and let $A$ be $\sigma$-unital $G$-$C^*$-Algebra. For a proper  locally compact Hausdorff $G$-space $X$ the equivariant $K$-homology with $G$ compact support and coefficients in $A$ is defined as
$$
\mathrm{colim}_{Y \subseteq X} KK^G(C_0(Y), A)
$$
where $Y \subseteq X$ runs through the $G$-compact subsets. Now, this is supposed to be a $G$-homology theory on the category of those proper spaces. However, no author I've seen actually goes into any detail about this but they all reference this paper by Kasparov:

G. Kasparov. Novikov’s conjecture on higher signatures: the operator Ktheory
approach. In Representation theory of groups and algebras, pages
79–99. Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1993

Unfortunately, I cannot find it anywhere online and it doesn't seem to be available at my university. Do you know a different source where this is proven?

Thank you.

Comment: The expression under the colimit does not seem to depend on $Y$...